# How to control the page size of the PDF generated from Visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, pdf

**Background**

I am generating a PDF using this visualforce page:

```
<apex:page controller="ExampleController" renderAs="pdf" applyBodyTag="false">
    <head>
        <style>
            @page { margin: 0.25in; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <apex:outputText value="{!body}" escape="false" />
</apex:page>
```

And this apex controller:

```
public without sharing class ExampleController {

    private final String body;

    public ExampleController() {
        body = '<i>html content goes here</i>';
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }
}
```

The PDF file it generates is the usual A4-ish page size.

I would like the PDF to be a small square, let's say:

- Height: 400px
- Width: 400px

**Question**

1. Is there any way to control the page size of the PDF generated by Salesforce visualforce pages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify the page size using the [CSS size attribute](https://flyingsaucerproject.github.io/flyingsaucer/r8/guide/users-guide-R8.html#xil_34).

```
<style>
    @page { margin: 0.25in; size: 4in 4in; }
</style>
```

You won't find this in the standard Salesforce documentation, but the Flying Saucer guide I linked to should provide a lot of useful information.

Comment: Annoyingly, I had tried `size: 4cm 4cm;` and it didn't seem to work... but inches did. thanks

Comment: @Robs Odd. Might be because VF uses an older version of Flying Saucer? At the very least, you can convert it pretty easily.